# Unparseable date in java

Tags: java, date

I'm using java studio creator to build my application. I used the ajax component, Popup Calendar, and when I want to get the date and compare it with another date , I cann't :(.
This is my code :

```
// My Code

  SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

  java.util.Calendar startDate = java.util.Calendar.getInstance(); 
  startDate.setTime(dateFormat.parse(startField.getValue().toString()));   
//
```

Where startField is the calendar..

I tried to set the dateformattedpattern in the properties of the calendar to be the same as dataformat but it gave an exception.

Is there any suggestions to fix the problem?

Comment: What's the exception? What's the value of `startField.getValue().toString()`? ... ?

Comment: the exception is unparseable date.

Comment: And what's the value of `startField.getValue().toString()`?

Comment: See Jigar Joshi's answer then, try changing `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd")` to `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`startField.getValue().toString()` should be of the form `yyyy/MM/dd`

Comment: Try to print what does `startField.getValue().toString()` return.

Comment: I printed the date that is given from the calendar, it is 2011-06-16.